# Searching through an xml file with Python

Tags: python, xml, search

I have a python script that works fine with hard coded arguments, but when I try to turn it into a function it stops working.

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xmlsearch(search_query):
# Parse the XML file
   tree = ET.parse('gamelist.xml')
   root = tree.getroot()

# Find elements with a specific attribute value
   elements = root.findall(".//machine[@name='" + search_query + "']")

# Iterate over the found elements
   for element in elements:
    # Do something with the element
       name = element.get('name')
       desc = element.find('description').text
       year = element.find('year').text
       manf = element.find('manufacturer').text
 #   print(name, desc, year, manf)

   print(f"Name: {name}, Description: {desc}, Year: {year}, Manufacturer: {manf}")
```

When I run the script:

```
python xmlsearch.py("burningf")
```

it returns nothing. It should return the MAME xml file info for the the game "burningf".

Comment: The issue is not your function but passing a command line argument to python compiler. This will work at bottom of script `xmlsearch.py("burningf")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

##### Paste this in `xmlsearch.py`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

def xmlsearch(search_query):
# Parse the XML file
   tree = ET.parse('gamelist.xml')
   root = tree.getroot()

# Find elements with a specific attribute value
   elements = root.findall(".//machine[@name='" + search_query + "']")

# Iterate over the found elements
   for element in elements:
    # Do something with the element
       name = element.get('name')
       desc = element.find('description').text
       year = element.find('year').text
       manf = element.find('manufacturer').text
 #   print(name, desc, year, manf)

   print(f"Name: {name}, Description: {desc}, Year: {year}, Manufacturer: {manf}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmlsearch(sys.argv[1])
```

##### Run `python xmlsearch.py burningf`

Comment: All I get is: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'py'"

Comment: Edited my post, copy paste the code again, ro replace `xmlsearch.py` by `xmlsearch`

Comment: Also, the argument is still hard coded, with the "xmlsearch("burningf")" at the end.

Comment: Ok, you didn't asked anything about this 'feature' AFAIK

Comment: I recommend https://diveintopython.org/

Comment: It was the whole point of the question, how to pass an argument in without using hard-coded arguments.